# Wave equation PDE's

Tags: waves, resource-recommendations, education, mathematics, differential-equations

I'm taking a partial differential equations course and I think I need some practice solving the 1D and 2D wave equation with boundary conditions and initial conditions, do you have a book like the schaum or a pdf with solved exercises?

Comment: Welcome to Physics StackExchange! Unfortunately, as with most StackExchange sites, this isn't really a site for recommendations -- we're specifically about questions with objective answers. You might have better luck in the meta exchange, or on the chat!

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @linkhyrule5:  We have a [tag:resource-recommendations] tag and [guidance for using it](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/are-resource-recommendations-allowed), so I don't think this questions is off-topic for that reason.  (It might be a little too math-y for us, though.)

Comment: ... So we do. I guess I'm too used to said 'other sites'!